# MST and Uniquness Problems in Data Structure old-solved Ex?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

I ready for taking a P.hD Entrance Exam. one of old-solution problem of Data Structure is as follows:

Which of the following Claims is True about `MST` of Simple, Undirected, Weighted and Connected Graph `G`? (edge weights is not necessarily different.)

1) if lightest edge between any cut in G, be unique, then `MST` is unique.

2)If all edges weights be different, `MST` is unique.

3) if the weights of `e=(u, v)` be equal to maximum lightest edge in all paths between u and `v` then `e` be in the `MST`.

Answer: one of them is Correct.

Who can explain more, which is true? why? there is any proof or we must take an example or provide counterexample?

Comment: could you explain 3) better? I don't get it.

Comment: 1) and 2) both seem to be true.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Cut_property and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352163/show-that-theres-a-minimum-spanning-tree-if-all-edges-have-different-costs, respectively

Comment: You literally have the detailled proofs for your exact claims right there in those links

Comment: @NiklasB. 1 and 2 is true?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1657112/14578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some links and based on those links I will try to answer your question, but I'm not an expert on MST. I thought this could help you get some intuition, so i am posting this.

[Edited and Corrected. Thanks to @Niklas B. for pointing my mistake]

**1)** See this [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dakane/CSE101/Solutions4.pdf). Look at (d) number solution on page 3. It says `If the lightest edge in a graph is unique, then it must be part of every MST.`

So, according to the theorem, we can say that, `every unique lightest edge must belong to every MST`. And according to Problem it is said that `lightest edge between any cut is unique`. So, every edge in MST must be lightest. Thus, MST must be unique.

**2)** According to the link `@Niklas B` provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Uniqueness), you can see that `If each edge has a distinct weight then there will be only one, unique minimum spanning tree.` The proof is also there. So I think 2 is true.

**3)** See the link [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4942/finding-paths-with-smallest-maximum-edge-weight). As you've stated, `if the weights of e=(u, v) be equal to maximum lightest edge in all paths between u and v then e be in the MST.` Let's look at an example here.  [image]

We want to find the `smallest maximum weight edge.`. The easiest path(meaning the path with smallest maximum weight edge) from 1 to 2 is: `1 > 3 > 4 > 2`. Because the maximum edge weight is only 2. But if i cut it like this on the image, you see the lightest edge is 4.(Which is e). Obviously we cant include this, as it would violate property of MST. Therefore, 3 can't be true.

So, I think Both 1 and 2 are true. I hope it makes sense and help you a bit.

Comment: According to the links i gave you, it seems to me, one of them is correct. But, I'm not really an expert. btw, you can give answer to your question if you like when you have found a solution.

Comment: I think your argumentation for 1) is flawed. If the MST is unique, then the lighest edge is also part of every MST (there is only one). In fact (1) should be true due to the cut property

Comment: Thank you @Niklaus B. I understood it wrong and my answer was flawed. I have corrected it and stated the reason. Hope it helps someone.